# How can I write comments/hidden text in a post?

Tags: posts

When writing a post, is it possible to write text that is only visible when editing a post (comments intended exclusively for me) and not visible when when viewing the blog?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using WordPress [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) you can create a quick annotation shortcode.

```
add_shortcode( 'annotation', 'wpse47489_private_annotation' );

function wpse47489_private_annotation( $args, $content = '' ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) return '';
    return "<div class='hidden-annotation'>$content</div>";
}
```

This will return an empty string for anyone but administrators. You can always return an empty string `''` though, these annotations will be visible when editing the post.

Use in the content like so:

> Lorem ipsum!
>
> [annotation]find better introductory paragraph[/annotation]
>
> ...dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Comment: @1212w2 Please accept this answer if it solved your issue.